# Update query based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How do I add a condition to the the update query where in it will deal with two conditions,people born before the 31 Dec 1986 and after 31 Dec 1986?DOB values should come from the Table T1.So it should be like people born before 31 Dec 1986, perform one function and people born after 31 Dec 1986 do something else.

```
Update Table 1
Set id= T2.id
from Table 1 T1
Inner Join Table 2 T2
ON T1.Cid = T2.cid
and T1.Name = T2.Name
and T1.DOB = T2.DOB
```

Comment: What are the different functions that you say should be performed? Can you please add that into your question?

Comment: You'd have to use 2 separate statements. You can add a `WHERE` clause after the `JOIN`.

Comment: The different functions probably should be the additional attributes to the update statement depending on the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update different set of fields depending on the value of `DOB`, you could do something like the below:

```
Update T1
Set 
t1.id= T2.id,
t1.col2 = case when t1.dob < '1986-12-31' then t1.col2 else t2.col2 end,
t1.col3 = case when t1.dob > '1986-12-31' then t1.col3 else t2.col3 end
--More columns in the same way
from Table1 T1
Inner Join Table2 T2
ON T1.Cid = T2.cid
and T1.Name = T2.Name
and T1.DOB = T2.DOB
```

The idea is that we use `CASE` to check whether a particular row corresponds to the before 1987 range or after, and update it accordingly. We can update it either using values from `Table2` or some other values or expressions. If value is to remain unchanged, we just set the value in the `else` part to the current value of the column e.g. `else t1.col2`. Using the above, you can specify all the values that are to be included in the update in one go.